# Overloading operator ->* for smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++14, pointers, overloading

I am implementing a smart pointer class template and I want to overload `operator ->*` (even if it’s rarely done). I came across Scott Meyer’s article *[Implementing operator ->* for Smart Pointers](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf)*. The article is from 1999 so I decided to try to adapt the code for C++ 14 (using parameter packs and perfect forwarding) and to improve it by adding support for pointer to data member—Meyer’s implementation only supports pointer to member functions—(which is the first of the two remaining problems of Meyer’s implementation that are listed at the section “Loose Ends” of his article and that he gives the reader as exercises to solve).

I ended up with the following code that seems to work quite fine. Now I have two questions:

1. Is there anything that could be improved in my code?
2. How to solve the second remaining problem listed at the section “Loose Ends” of Meyer’s article? (*“You can’t use user-defined pointers-to-members. If someone has overloaded operator ->* to take objects that act like member pointers, you may want to support such ‘smart pointers to members’ in your smart pointer class. Unfortunately, you need traits classes to get the result type of such overloaded operator ->*.”*)

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Member_function_type_traits { };

template<typename O, typename... A, typename R>
struct Member_function_type_traits<R (O::*)(A...)> {
  typedef O Object_T;
  typedef R Return_T;
};

template<typename O, typename... A, typename R>
struct Member_function_type_traits<R (O::*)(A...) const> {
  typedef O Object_T;
  typedef R Return_T;
};

template<typename O, typename... A, typename R>
struct Member_function_type_traits<R (O::*)(A...) volatile> {
  typedef O Object_T;
  typedef R Return_T;
};

template<typename O, typename... A, typename R>
struct Member_function_type_traits<R (O::*)(A...) const volatile> {
  typedef O Object_T;
  typedef R Return_T;
};

template<typename T>
class Pending_member_function_call {
  typedef typename Member_function_type_traits<T>::Object_T Object_T;
  typedef typename Member_function_type_traits<T>::Return_T Return_T;
  std::pair<Object_T*, T> operands;  
  public:
    Pending_member_function_call(std::pair<Object_T*, T> opr): operands{opr} { }
    template<typename... U>
    Return_T operator ()(U&&... args) {
      return (operands.first->*operands.second)(std::forward<U>(args)...);
  }
};

template<typename T>
class Smart_pointer {
  T* ptr;
  public:
    Smart_pointer(T* ptr): ptr{ptr} { }
    ~Smart_pointer() { delete ptr; }
    // …
    // operator ->* overload for pointers to data member
    template<typename U, typename V>
    V operator ->*(V U::* pdm) const {
      return ptr->*pdm;
    }
    // operator ->* overload for pointers to member function
    template<typename U>
    Pending_member_function_call<U> operator ->*(U pmf) const {
      return std::make_pair(ptr, pmf);
    }
};

struct A {
  int dm{5};
  int mf(int x) { return 2 * x; }
};

int main() {
  Smart_pointer<A> p{new A};
  auto pdm = &A::dm;
  auto pmf = &A::mf;
  std::cout << "A::dm called: " << p->*pdm << '\n';
  std::cout << "A::mf called: " << (p->*pmf)(8) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to delete the copy constructor and the assignment operator of `Smart_pointer` otherwise you are going to end up wiht a double delete.

Comment: Why a double delete? You can implement smart pointers with copy semantics.

Comment: You can. But unless you either delete the copy constructor or implement the copy semantics you are going to get a double delete. The default compiler generated copy constructor is doing the wrong thing. Look-up "Rule of Three (five)".

Comment: See: [Unique Ptr](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2014/12/30/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer/) Followed by [Shared Ptr](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/15/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-ii/) followed by [Smart Pointer Constructors](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/23/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-iii/)

Comment: Okay. Actually I am using my own copy constructor and copy assignment operator but thanks for the links, I will look at them. At the moment I used the implementation of `unique_ptr` from the _GNU C++ Library_ and chapter VII of _Modern C++ Design_ on smart pointers by Andrei Alexandrescu. What sources did you use for your articles?

Comment: My articles are based on issues people had creating their own smart pointers that were posted here (on stack exchange) for review. I was looking for common mistakes (like missing copy constructor/move constructor) and comparing them to the standard implementation. I did not read any specific articles when writing these but I have read many smart pointer articles over the years.

Comment: I've just read your articles. Thank you because they were extremely helpful, especially the subtle error when directly swapping in constructors _with implicit cast_ (section "Derived Type Assignment"), the special treatment of nullptr (section "The nullptr") and the `bool` conversion using the new C++11 `explicit` keyword that avoids the nasty workaround of C++03 for smart pointers in boolean contexts (section "Problem 5: Bool conversion to easy").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there anything that could be improved in my code?

I think you can accomplish the same thing in much less code with just a lambda:

```
template <class U>
auto operator->*(U pmf) const {
    return [=](auto&&... args){
        return (ptr->*pmf)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Could have a `static_assert` on [`std::is_member_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_pointer) for extra safety.

> How to solve the second remaining problem listed at the section “Loose Ends” of Meyer’s article?

I believe the lambda solves this problem as well.

---

Also you could consider `const` propagation. If the `Smart_pointer` is `const`, do you really want to allow calling non-`const` member functions? I don't know. If you decide you don't, you should provde both a `const` and non-`const` overload and forward to a helper:

```
template <class U>
auto operator->*(U pmf) {
    return pending_mem_fun(ptr, pmf);
}

template <class U>
auto operator->*(U pmf) const {
    return pending_mem_fun(const_cast<T const*>(ptr), pmf);
}
```

where `pending_mem_fun` doesn't actually have to be a member function.

Comment: Lambdas of course! Very elegant solution, thanks. No, I don't want to allow calling non-`const` member functions when the type of the resource held by the smart pointer is `const` (same behavior as plain pointers). However your lambda already provides that, so there is no need to use two overloads and a helper instead: I think they implement the opposite behavior (they allow calling non-`const`member functions) and you meant “If you decide you _do_”.

Comment: @Maggyero No, I meant what I said. With the lambda solution, a `const Smart_pointer<T>` can call non-`const` pointer-to-member functions. You'd have to use the alternate solution to disallow that. The reason is the difference between the type `T* const` (const pointer-to-non-const T) and `T const*`(non-const pointer to const T)

Comment: I thought you were talking about `Smart_pointer<const T>`, not `const Smart_pointer<T>`. But then why would someone want to prevent `const Smart_pointer<T>` from calling non-`const` member functions? Plain `T* const` do not prevent it: a `const` pointer is not a pointer-to-`const`. And I don't think it is good design to prevent it for smart pointers. Only `Smart_pointer<const T>` should prevent it, and they already do naturally with your lambda implementation and mine.